# how to get today's date in java(yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: java, date

how could I get today's date (current system date) on format yyyy-mm-dd (just date and not dateTime) to compare with some other dates of the same format.

Comment: This is duplicate question

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format a [`new Date()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date--):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formatted = df.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String formatted = format1.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println(formatted);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
but what if want to have this date in a java date object?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a variable in this format.

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println( date );
```